# Есть ли у сайта Русский язык страница на Area 51?

Tags: поддержка

Есть ли у сайта Русский язык страница на Area 51?

Искал, но не нашел. Есть [только одно упоминание](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/a/21309/137807).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Такой страницы нет. Как и ru.SO, этот сайт не был создан через Area 51. В случае с ru.SO, импортированний сайт был вручную соединён с уже существующим планом на Area 51. Для этого сайта такого плана не было.

Comment: Возможно, стоит запросить её создание? Это все-таки визитная карточка сайта в общей системе. С нее какой-нибудь трафик будет.

Comment: [О проблемах сайта Русский язык](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1394)

Comment: @NormalHuman Действительно, вина моя определенно есть. Постараюсь обсудить с командой проблему.